# Help with XML path views

Tags: xml, eclipse

is there any tool that will give me a view for XML fields like so.

```
<Service>
 <header/> 
 <Body>
  <element1/>
  <element2/>
 </Body>
</Service>
```

I want something that will show me the a view like so, if i select element1

Service/Body/element1

Is there any tool for eclipse for doing the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Eclipse J2EE edition](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/), or if you install the [Eclipse WTP (Web Tool Platform)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), you will have a view able to show XML content (it will include the [XML component](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/xml/overview.html)).

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/newandnoteworthy/sourceediting/outline-comments.png))</sub>

See:

- [News and Noteworthy features for WTP 3.1 (June 2009) Source Editing Service](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/newandnoteworthy/sourceediting.php)
- other [new features for the upcoming WTP 3.2](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/news/main.php)

Answer (score 0):

It'll actually be written in that form on the editor's status line, as well.

Selecting an Element will show you its "path" while selecting an Attribute will include it but swap the icon to the correct one.